# paypal-checkout sandbox card declined on heroku but accepted on localhost

Tags: reactjs, heroku, paypal

I've got a react app using [paypal-checkout](https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout). I've created test cards for the app via paypal's developer site and i'm running it in sandbox mode locally.

Checkouts are working fine locally.

However when I try to do the same checkouts on the heroku hosted app under sandbox mode and with the same test credit cards it tells me 'card declined'?

Does sandbox mode only work locally?

I would have thought I'd be able to run sandbox mode on the hosted heroku app with test credit cards?

Not getting any errors in the console so don't have much to work with, anyone else run into this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

do you happen to have to whitelist a url (one that isn't localhost:*) in your dev settings on paypal?

Comment: I also thought this

Comment: Yep, this is the first thing I thought. Found https://www.paypal.com/us/smarthelp/article/how-do-i-whitelist-my-server%E2%80%99s-ip-address-so-it-can-access-paypal-apis-ts1926 but my account does not have access to the manager portal. You'd think ti'd be all under the developer.paypal.com area. Still digging

Comment: so from what i'm reading it should just work. going to triple-check my keys and retry. did their integration survey and asked for better documentation on this front.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE - started working.

It was either a combination of time between creating the REST API Keys and paypal ok'ing them to their servers or deleting the config fields in the heroku app and re-adding them but it's working now.

I think though the rule of thumb with Heroku and Paypal is that it's easier to delete and re-create a config variable in Heroku and reboot the server, than edit it, save it and hope it'll take the new value.

Thanks bobber205 & Simon Franzen.

Best.